# EXT JS : DataStore filter function is not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am having issues in using filter with EXT JS datastore. 
I am getting an array of jsonobjects as response and below are two types of the response objects.

Object 1 -

ITEMCODE : "2500"
   ISNEW :"false"

Object 2 -

ITEMCODE : "2200"
   ISNEW :"true"

I am using below code to filter the datastore and binding it to the combobox.

```
 MyApp.Data.Store.clearFilter(true);


                    MyApp.Data.Store.filter({
                        property: 'ISNEW',
                        value: 'true',
                        exactMatch: true
                    });

     console.log(MyApp.Data.Store);
```

I am trying to show only the objects with **ISNEW = true** but somehow, the filtration does not take place and after the filteration, when I am printing the datastore, it shows all the records and not only records with **ISNEW = true** .

Please help me in figuring out where I am going wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try filterBy function if it helps:

```
    MyApp.Data.Store.filterBy(function(record, id){
            if (record.get("ISNEW") == "true") {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
    }, this);
```

Best!!

Comment: You can simplify your code by returning the boolean value from the comparison: `return record.get("ISNEW") === "true";`